# Function similar to os.listdir(), but i can see step by step adding it to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, path, listdir

I am looking for a function or a way, something similar to os.listdir(), however, I need to add the dir various times into the list depending on the path.
For example:

```
os.listdir(path)
```

Output:

```
['Bacon.png', 'Basics.png', 'Cabbage.png', 'Elf.png', 'Flip Flop.png', 'Prisoner.png', 'Santa Blue.png']
```

I need something like this:

```
['Bacon','Bacon','Bacon','Bacon', 'Basics', 'Basics', 'Cabbage', 'Elf', 'Elf', 'Elf', 'Flip Flop', 'Prisoner', 'Prisoner', 'Santa Blue']
```

Basically, I need to multiply the number of times listdir imports the path or item into the list.
Thank you for any help and interactions.

Comment: What is the logic for how many times you multiply a name? Why is `Bacon` added 4 times, but `Basics` is only added 2 times?

Comment: @Barmar it depends. That will be set differently depending on what is the path, more specifically what is the picture, as you can see above those are png files. Depending on which file is being imported into the list, the number of times it will be imported. That will be set manually before.

Comment: But the path is the same for all the files, why do they have different repetitions?

Comment: @Barmar the path is the same yes and the different repetitions are basically weights of items. Afterwards im picking items from this list and it has to be weighted. I need to automize it, because there are different paths in the list and it contains over 150 items.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    result.extend([os.path.splitext(filename)[0]] * repetitions(path, filename))
```

`repetitions()` is a function you can write that determines the number of times the filename should be multiplied.